# Getting a value of a checked Radio Button as String and store it on Firebase

Tags: android, string, firebase-realtime-database, radio-button, radio-group

I designed a sign up activity in AS. I want to get some information from the user. One of them is their gender.

I used RadiGroup and RadioButton to do the task.
At the moment I want to store the user's information on Firebase, but when I want to convert the radio button value to String, it doesn't work. I mean it works but doesn't send it to Firebase Database.

I checked some similar questions, but I couldn't get my head around it.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag. Aside from that, it'll be hard to help without seeing the code that causes the problem. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read it carefully please, as it's quite useful).

Comment: please show some code. How can we help you like this?

Comment: Please add the code that you are using and please also respond with @.